# saving a PNG image as vector PDF in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

Ive a script to generate an image using imagemagick in PHP, after designing i need to create a pdf to print and this pdf need to be like a vector one, even if we zoom in the content should be crisp, but my pdf is not so, can some one guide me how to achieve this?
Do i need to convert my final png as svg? or is it possible to make pdf with PNG as vector?

Comment: Converting an image into vector graphics is usually not working properly. Try it on [http://vectormagic.com/](http://vectormagic.com/). Maybe you can instead simply use a higher resolution of your png so it stays crisp on zooming.

Comment: That won't be possible. You can try to analyse the PNG and use one of the PHP SVG libraries, but that's a whole bunch of work. If you haven't got a source image with higher resolution, there is no other solution.